# Как сделать переключение между несколькими слайдерами bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, карусель

Возникла проблема со слайдером бутсраповским, у меня их несколько штук на странице, они могут добавляться через базу данных и проблема состоит в том что мне надо реализовать переключение между всем каруселями на данной странице по кнопкам "прев." и "некст", но не знаю как это сделать что бы оно брало слайд со следующего слайдера

Comment: вот сам код слайдера https://jsfiddle.net/fmbwqqt4/

Comment: 1) Код трудно читать. Приведите в порядок отступы и пустые строки, пожалуйста. 2) Уточните задачу. Пользователь щёлкает по кнопке "следующий", и при достижении последнего слайда в карусели его перекидывает на следующую карусель?

Comment: Да, просто слайды со следующего слайдера подхватываются слайды

Comment: Что значит "просто подхватываются"? На странице несколько наборов слайдов, но где бы не начал их перелистывать, увидишь все слайды из всех наборов?

Comment: Да, открываю слайдер 1 открываются слайды с него и при перелистывании слайдов нам начинают листаться слайды с этого слайдера и потом слайды со следующенго подхватываются и так со всеми

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, её можно решить, заполнив все карусели одним и тем же наборов слайдов. Этот набор будет содержать все слайды из всех каруселей.

Поскольку ваш код собирает карусели без индикаторов и стрелок назад/вперёд, карусели будут отличаться только тем, у какого слайда стоит класс `active`.

И вашим каруселям не нужны идентификаторы. Их используют индикаторы и стрелки, которых у вас нет.

### PHP

Обрабатывая запрос к БД, надо сначала заполнить все карусели всеми слайдами, а потом уже вывести их на экран.

Можно посчитать количество записей в запросе и завести массив с таким же количеством строк. Обрабатывая каждую запись из запроса, надо добавлять очередную порцию слайдов ко всем элементам массива. И в нужный момент назначать класс `active` первому слайду очередного набора.

### jQuery

Можно написать скрипт, который после загрузки страницы проходит по всем каруселям и дополняет их клонами слайдов из других каруселей. Понадобятся методы jQuery:

- http://jquery-docs.ru/core/each/
- http://jquery-docs.ru/manipulation/clone/
- http://jquery-docs.ru/manipulation/appendto/
- http://jquery-docs.ru/Manipulation/prependTo/

Например, сначала пройти по всем слайдам во всех каруселях и собрать массив соответствий { номер слайда на странице <-> номер карусели на странице }. Потом пройти по массиву, клонируя слайды.

Comment: @AndreyKekc Обновил свой ответ. Поскольку ваш код собирает карусели без индикаторов и стрелок, будет относительно просто поменять пхп-код так, чтобы он сразу наполнил все карусели всеми возможными слайдами и назначил слайды, с которых должна начинать каждая карусель.